# iOSの動画同時再生がしたい

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, swift2

iOSの動画同時再生を行うにはどの様に実装すれば良いでしょうか？

iPad で4つの動画を同時再生したいです。

iOSアプリ開発会社 TouchPress のアプリでは実装できています。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nK54PvY_nAQ&feature=youtu.be&t=72

Answer (score 1):

完全な解答でありませんが、YouTube の動画であれば、以前、次の LBYouTubeView を使用したところ複数同時再生が出来ました。

- https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

Comment: コメントでコードの入れかたが分からなかったので、下記↓に入れます。

Answer (score 0):

@Nyoho
ありがとうございます！ LBYouTubeView を試してみます。

実は AVPlayerViewController を複数使うことで再生できました。

複数の AVPlayer を生成し、各AVPlayer を AVPlayerViewController にセットし、各AVPlayerViewController の表示位置を決めます。

```
let movieUrl : NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)

let each_player = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
let each_playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

each_playerController.player = each_player
each_playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false

let x_position:CGFloat = self.thumbnailMovieWidth * contents_count
each_playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(x_position, 0, self.thumbnailMovieWidth, self.thumbnailMovieHeight)

self.addChildViewController(each_playerController)

//サムネイルをスクロールビューに入れる
self.buttomThumbnailMoviesScrollView.addSubview(each_playerController.view)
```